# Clarifying the purpose of [tagname]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

<del>Sup dawgs, I heard you like meta posts about tag names, so we put a tag name in your tag name so you can meta while you meta.</del>

The [tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagname) tag currently has no summary, [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tagname/info) or [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tagname/synonyms). It mainly seems to be used for questions about [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29489160/420009) or [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29141390/4200092) tag names (specifically, the `tagName` property), though there are a few cases where it's used for something else:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5703237/4200092) uses it to refer to [tagging with git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23713634/4200092) asks about tagging as a general concept.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27788392/4200092) seems to be using it for some other reason (and appears to be off-topic).

My inclination would be to add a tag summary/wiki page to explicitly state that [tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagname) refers to the `tagName` property of (X/HT)ML tags, since we already have [git-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tag) for git questions and [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagging) (or [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags)) for general cases. The only other use I can think of is #twitter #hashtags and the [hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashtag) tag takes care of those.

Comment: Only 36 questions ? Let's clean it up !

Comment: @JonasCz I just wanted to be sure that there weren't any other possible uses for "tag name" before I charged ahead and started changing things (I doubt that there are, but you never know).

Comment: `...state that tagname refers to the tagName property of (X/HT)ML tags` I'd also rename it to [html-tagname], if possible, and also create an [xml-tagname] tag, as there are some questions about that. Looking through the questions, I don't see it being used for anything else, and googling it shows that is almost exclusively used for HTML.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm not sure about that; the `tagName` property is pretty much the same thing for XML and HTML.

Comment: My vote is for [html-tagname] and [xml-tagname].  They are more descriptive, more discoverable, and will be more illustrative when they show up in the tag dropdown.